# jQuery event is executed once only (Primefaces 3.2, JSF 2.2)

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable, toggle

We are using primefaces,jsf.

I have following datatable:

```
<p:dataTable var="dataRow"
                first="#{wirkungsgradeEditBean.firstRowIndex}"
                value="#{wirkungsgradeEditBean.wirkgradList}" editable="true"
                id="table" paginator="true"
                rows="#{wirkungsgradeEditBean.rowsPerPage}"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="15,25,35">
                <p:column headerText="#{msg.table_wirkungsgrade_wirk4}">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{dataRow.wirk4}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{dataRow.wirk4}" required="true" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="#{msg.column_head_edit}">
                    <p:rowEditor />
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close"
                        rendered="#{wirkungsgradeEditBean.renderDeleteButton}"
                        styleClass="rainstar-button-small-edit"
                        action="#{wirkungsgradeEditBean.btn_deleteEntryClick()}"
                        update=":form:table" widgetVar="delBut" >
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{dataRow}"
                            target="#{wirkungsgradeEditBean.selectedWirkgrad}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
                <p:ajax event="rowEdit"
                    listener="#{wirkungsgradeEditBean.btn_editEntryClick}"
                    update=":form:table" />
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                    listener="#{wirkungsgradeEditBean.selectRo()}"
                    update=":form:table" />
            </p:dataTable>
```

Now I want to toggle the delete button when the edit button (pencil symbol) is pressed. I do that with the following jquery construct:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("span.ui-row-editor span").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().children("button").toggle();
        });
    });
```

If I try this the first time, all is fine. But if I try it again, the toggle is not happening.

What is wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

When you click edit button, there is a partial update, table is recreated and your handler is lost. It is safer to control delete button through JSF, just update `wirkungsgradeEditBean.renderDeleteButton` upon edit accordingly.

EDIT:
Another option would be to use on function:

```
$(document).on("click", "span.ui-row-editor span", function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().children("button").toggle();
});
```

You can fine tune it to something more localized instead of document, but not affected by partial updates.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  $(this).parent().parent().children("button").toggle();
```

you can use

```
  $(this).parent().siblings("button").toggle();
```